# Why do I get this ERROR message when I try to sign up?

Tags: php, error-handling

Why do I get this error?

> Call to undefined function `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Has it something to do with being old code?

Comment: Yup, PHP7 removed `mysql_*` functions, thus you are getting such message. :)

Comment: What is the version of your PHP executable, you can find that using, running `php -v` in the CLI.

Comment: Try to sign up for what? Is it your site?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using PHP 7, in which many new features were added and the already deprecated item, `mysql_*` were removed, thus, it would generate an function alert just as you faced. So use either, `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. But don't mix DB apis!